# Partial derivative with respect to a function of variables

Tags: functions, derivatives, partial-derivative, self-learning

I got the following equation, and want to solve the effect of $\Delta\alpha,\Delta\beta, and \Delta\gamma$ :

$g=\alpha\frac{d}{d+e+f}+\beta\frac{e}{d+e+f}+\gamma\frac{f}{d+e+f}$

However, $\alpha,\beta, and \gamma$ are all the functions, like the following:

$\alpha = \frac{a}{d}$ ; $\beta=\frac{b}{e}$ ; $\gamma=\frac{c}{f}$

So, the equation end up:

$g=\frac{a}{d}\frac{d}{d+e+f}+\frac{b}{e}\frac{e}{d+e+f}+\frac{c}{f}\frac{f}{d+e+f}$

How can I find the effect of Δα,Δβ,andΔγ when they are all in functions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you mean by “effect”?

Comment: Thanks! I mean the marginal effect of alpha/beta/gamma contributed to the g. @José Carlos Santos

Comment: When dealing with partial derivatives, you need to be explicit about which variables you're holding constant. For example, a change in $\alpha$ might be due to a change in $d$ while $a$ is held constant, or the converse. Each will have different answers.

Comment: When not being lazy, we first write $g$ as a function of *independent variables* (i.e. $a,b,c,d,e,f$) and then express a partial derivative like $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}\vert_{b,c,d,e,f}$ in order to express that $b,c,d,e,f$ are being held constant. When $g$ is written as a function like $g(a,b,c,d,e,f)$, then it is understood from context that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$ holds $b,c,d,e,f$ constant.

Comment: @DerekHo Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let apply **chain rule**

we have

$$g=g(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \quad g=\frac{a+b+c}{d+e+f}$$ 
and 
$$\alpha=\alpha(a,d) \quad \beta=\beta(b,e) \quad \gamma=\gamma(c,f)$$

thus

$$dg=\frac{\partial g}{\partial \alpha}d\alpha+\frac{\partial g}{\partial \beta}d\beta+\frac{\partial g}{\partial \gamma}d\gamma$$

with

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial d}\frac{\partial d}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{d}{d+e+f}+\frac{-1}{(d+e+f)^2}\cdot \left(-\frac{a}{\alpha^2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{d}{d+e+f}+\frac{d^2}{a(d+e+f)^2}$$

and so on

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial \beta}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial e}\frac{\partial e}{\partial \beta}=...$$

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \gamma}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial \gamma}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \gamma}=...$$

Comment: This works if $g$ is a function only of $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$. However, it seems to be a function of $6$ independent variables. Implicit in your answer is the idea that $d,e$ and $f$ are held constant.

Comment: @Myridium Yes of course you are right!

Comment: Thanks both of you. However, $d$ should not be constant if the change in $\alpha$ is due to the change of $d$. @Myridium

Comment: @DerekHo note that the given solution has not limitation about the variability of the involved variables